# How do I add a class in Laravel so it is available in Blade?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I would like to create a class in Laravel, and make it available in Blade. Details below:

```
class myHelper {

    function clear_alias($string)
    {
        $string = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
        $string = strtolower($string);
        $string = strtr($string, array('&' => '_', '"' => '-', '&'.'#039;' => '-', '<' => '-', '>' => '-', '\'' => ''));
        $string = preg_replace('/^[^a-z0-9]{0,}(.*?)[^a-z0-9]{0,}$/si', '\\1', $string);
        $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-]/', '-', $string);
        $string = preg_replace('/[\-]{2,}/', '-', $string);
        return $string;
    }

    function cut_text($string,$char=100)
    {
        $string = strip_tags($string);

        if (strlen($string) > $char)
        {
            $string=substr($string, 0, $char);
            for ($a=strlen($string)-1;$a>=0;$a--)
            {
                if ($string[$a]==" ")
                {
                    $string=substr($string, 0, $a)."...";
                    break;
                };
            };
        };
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: you need to either create a static class, or add your class to the container and call using app()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place your class in the autoload part in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Helpers/MyHelper.php"
```

Then run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: additionally, if class is static you can just call direct from blade, if not you need to add to container and call with app('MyClass)->someMethod()

Answer (score -2):

I think you should place your class in /app/MyClass.php and then use it in your controller:

use \App\MyClass;

Kind regards

Comment: not exactly what you want to do with a helper class